# Embedded Internet Explorer and hashchange event

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, bind

When using Internet Explorer and I'd like to bind to hashchanged event, no JavaScript function is evaluated.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function()
{
    alert ( 'HasChange' );
}
```

On 'real' Internet Explorer using the integrated webserver, I get the correct action.

```
this.NavigateTo = function(newPath)
{
    window.location.hash = '#' + newPath;
    alert ( 'Navigate' );
};
```

'Navigate' will be alerted, but no 'HasChange'.

Is there a method to retrieve the Debugger by F12 for embedded Internet Explorer? I got this behaviour when Internet Explorer is embedded in System.Windows.Forms and WPF. No change when I create a 32-Bit, 64-Bit or AnyCPU Executable.

Or is this behaviour even known?

Answer (score 1):

I think that by default the embedded IE behaves like IE7, so you won't get any event that was added in later versions unless you modify the integration to make it behave as the latest version available in the computer

Comment: Is it possible to change the behaviour or is this not intended by Microsoft?

Seems you are right: 
4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0E; Zune 4.7; Creative AutoUpdate v1.40.04)

Comment: Yes, I think that it's possible to change that but I don't remember now the site where I did read it.

Comment: Has anybody found out how we can force the version of the embedded browser?